# Delete Prisma self-referencing (one to many)

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, self-reference, self-referencing-table

I have this prisma schema

```
model Directory {
  id                String      @id @default(cuid())
  name              String?
  parentDirectoryId String?
  userId            String
  parentDirectory   Directory?  @relation("parentDirectoryId", fields: [parentDirectoryId], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  user              User        @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  quizess           Quiz[]
  subDirectory      Directory[] @relation("parentDirectoryId")

  @@index([parentDirectoryId])
  @@index([userId])
}
```

The logic behind it:
I can have a folder that can be in root (parentDirectoryId = null) or it can have many additionals directories.

How do I delete directory with directiories inside of them?

This is what happens when I try to call prisma.delete:

`Invalid` prisma.directory.delete()` invocation:

The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'parentDirectoryId' between the `Directory` and `Directory` models.`

Set onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade which doesnt work

Comment: I'm actually on the same problem but there's no answer here, have you solved it yet?

Comment: Can you please update the post with the query you performed?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let directories = await this.prisma.directory.findFirst({
        where: { id: directory.id },
        include: { subDirectory: true },
      });

prisma.directory.update({
   data: {
           subDirectory: {
               disconnect: directories.subDirectory.map((e) => {
                  return { id: e.id };
               }),
            },
          },
})
```

The `directory` is the father directory.